# How to setup a material that shows the texture under an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'd like to setup a material in cycles that looks like what is underneath and projected upward (Blender 2.79). It should behave like a refraction, except the ray always goes down instead of following the normal of the object surface and the IOR. By carefully working with textures, this effect can be achieved like in this image, but this is not practical for a complex case.

In the example below, the same material is used and in all of the geometry. This effect can be achieved by careful setup. However, if multiple items, with different materials are under the cone and dome, this approach is not practical. If uv maps are used, there is not an easy way to achieve this effect. If the cone and dome are animated to move or change shape, matching the texture is difficult also.

[image]

I'd like to be able to use something like the refraction shader to achieve this effect. The image below shows the use of the refraction shader. However, the result is not close enough because the change in ray direction depends on the geometry and IOR.

[image]

[image]

Is there a node setup that will achieve something like the first image using the refraction shader or any other combination of shaders?

Comment: Why not simply use the same vertically projected  material?

Comment: @Duarte, is there a way to project from the plane upward in the example above? I could not find a way to do that. Will it work if multiple items with different materials are projected upward?

Comment: It seems to be what your first image already shows, just use basic 2D world coordinates for your texture, and it should use scene coordinates to project from the top